# Continuous Backup Software for Windows 2003 Server

Tags: backup, cdp

I am looking for a software package that does continuous data backup of file shares on a single server.  Backup location would be a NAS over a VPN tunnel.  File Versioning is a must.  Any recommendations?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at FalconStor's CDP offerings. Their stuff is industry leading and seems a bit enterprisey, and as such it might be overkill for you. If you want something a little better in price, SonicWall apparently makes [decent CDP appliances](http://www.sonicwall.com/us/products/908.html) that should be able to scale down to just one file server. I was looking heavily at them recently. Maybe the SonicWall CDP 110 would be enough for you.

**EDIT**: In light of new information, there are a lot of software possibilities out there. One possibility that seems to be best for you is

- Replay 4 by http://www.appassure.com/

However, some heavy hitters exist, but might be out of your pricerange:

- Symantec's NetBackup RealTimehttp://www.symantec.com/en/uk/business/netbackup-realtime-protection
- EMC's RecoverPoint http://www.emc.com/products/detail/software/recoverpoint.htm
- AIMStor CDP http://www.cofio.com/Continuous-Data-Protection/

Comment: Thanks, both products are interesting, but not exactly what i am looking for.  I guess I should have mentioned I have a $1000 budget and would like to keep it software based.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only product I can think of that can do both CDP and file versioning at the same time is [Cofio's](http://www.cofio.com) AIMstor.

Falconstor is a nice product (and nice company) but can't do it as its a volume replication product and has no notion of logical entities such as files.

Another issue with volume base replication is its indiscriminate to what it replicates so you cant tune out parts of the filesystem that generate noise but has no business value.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Symantec's offering in the past but have found it to be *incredibly* bandwidth-sensitive, and would honestly hesitate to recommend it.  I'm wondering though if you might be able to cook up something using DFS and Volume Shadow Copy?  It might be more snapshotty than truly continuous, but otherwise it would seem to satisfy the requirement.